# Blocked Android camera

Tags: android, camera

I'm working on application which using camera. Time to time, in time of application debuging a cannot release camera correctly (by camera.release()). Does anybody know how to unblock camera for future use? I know, I can restart cell phone, but it takes a too long time :(

Comment: If terminating your process in DDMS does not do it, then I suspect that a reboot is the only answer.